# Skype-style infobox to bottom right corner of screen with PyQt4

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

What I understand skype is developed in Qt, and skype has information boxes that appear on bottom right. Can I make these information boxes with `PyQt4` running on `Ubuntu`? "Infobox" means something like [that](http://help.admin.mtu.edu/docs/images/1/14/New_program_available.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are custom widgets.

There is little documentation on creating these widgets in PyQt online, but here are two pages which may be useful: [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/customwidgets/) and the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-pyqtdesigner.html).

There should also be some examples in your installation of PyQt. `/usr/share/doc/python-qt4-doc/examples` is the location on my debian machine.

Comment: I want transparent background. If widget's background has transparent parts, I see throught the widget. Like Windows's desktop-widgets, but I use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

For `Mac OS` [Growl](http://growl.info/applications.php?cat=Chat) is such an notification system. `Ubuntu` has a similar notification system called [NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD). Here are some [examples](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines#Layout_cases_.28with_examples_in_C.2C_Python_and_C.23.29) for python using that framework.